# How to reset the className of all elements when I click reset button in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a bingo card that I can click on a number to make it marked and then click to unmark it. I seem to have that part working. What I want to do now is have a reset button that when I click it sets all the numbers to unmarked.

I was thinking about keeping track of which numbers were clicked and on reset to apply the className .singleBox to all the numbers that are in marked state. However, I am not even sure how to accomplish that since there is a 1 event lag each time I click on the number.

Here is my code.

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.target.className == "singleBox" ? "colorBox" : "singleBox";
    //console.log(clickedNumbers);
  };


const handleReset = () => {};

  const checkClicked = (index) => {
    if (index > 0) return "singleBox";
    else return "no-box";
  };



return (
    <>
      <section className="card">
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
        <table className="myTable" id="cardNum">
          {rows.map((cs, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <tr className="singleRow">
                  {cs.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <td
                          className={checkClicked(index)}
                          onClick={index > 0 && handleClick}
                        >
                          {i}
                        </td>
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </section>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: I figured out an alternative way to do this and it is working perfectly.